# How I can return varchar in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have this record **[sip:+3xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xx;user=phone; *tel:+3xxxxxxxxx;*]**, **[*tel:+3xxxxxxxxxx*;cpc=ordinary].**
I want to return varchar ***from *tel: to the ;****. I was try with function `**SUBSTR()**`, but, because the position is not fixed at all records does not return accurate records. Аlso the, **`REGEXP_LIKE()`** function returns my full records not just the part I need. Can you tell me what is the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` we can try:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'tel:[^;]+;')
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '[sip:+3xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xx;user=phone; tel:+3xxxxxxxxx;], [tel:+3xxxxxxxxxx;cpc=ordinary]' AS col FROM dual
)
```